# AD group membership changes not reflected in winbind information

Tags: samba, groups

I have inherited several RHEL5 servers that were set up to authenticate users against their AD accounts via winbind.  Everything works fine until I update group membership in AD.  For some users, the changes never make it to the output of the "groups" command, although they are reflected in the output of "getent group <groupname>".

For example, consider the following:

[root@hcc1pl1 ~]# groups plubans
plubans : domain users systems infrastructure development
[root@hcc1pl1 ~]# getent group q1esb
q1esb:*:23136:q1qai,q1prodi

If I add myself to q1esb on the DC that winbind is using, you can see that the membership is updated:

[root@hcc1pl1 ~]# lsof -i | grep winbind
winbindd  31339    root   17u  IPv4 63817934       TCP hcc1pl1:56541->hcnas01:microsoft-ds (ESTABLISHED)
winbindd  31339    root   21u  IPv4 63817970       TCP hcc1pl1:53622->hcnas01:ldap (ESTABLISHED)
[root@hcc1pl1 ~]# ldapsearch -u -x -LLL -h hcnas01 -D "plubans@XXX.XXX" -W -b "CN=Peter Lubans,OU=Standard User Accounts,OU=Users,OU=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XXX" "(sAMAccountName=*)" memberOf
Enter LDAP Password:
...
memberOf: CN=q1esb,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,OU=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XXX
...

Note that winbind is running without caching (-n flag):

[root@hcc1pl1 ~]# ps -ef | grep winbind
root     31339     1  0 13:50 ?        00:00:00 winbindd -n
root     31340 31339  0 13:50 ?        00:00:00 winbindd -n
root     31351 31339  0 13:50 ?        00:00:00 winbindd -n
root     31352 31339  0 13:50 ?        00:00:00 winbindd -n
root     31353 31339  0 13:50 ?        00:00:00 winbindd -n

Now getent shows that that group has the correct members:

[root@hcc1pl1 ~]# getent group q1esb
q1esb:*:23136:q1qai,plubans,q1prodi

But the updated membership is not reflected in my account details:

[root@hcc1pl1 ~]# groups plubans
plubans : domain users systems infrastructure development
[root@hcc1pl1 ~]#

The truly vexing part of this problem is that it works fine for other accounts on this machine, and for my account on machines that I have configured from the ground up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you fine a solution for that?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that this was caused by group information being cached at logon-time in /var/cache/samba/netsamlogon_cache.tdb.  I guess that although '-n' instructed winbind not to cache it's queries against LDAP, the presence of the membership information in that TDB file was enough to mess things up.

Comment: So how do I "refresh" that log-on info? I have logged out of the linux box and log in again but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get ahold of Marcin's lost article (https://marcinm.co.uk/group-membership-not-updating-in-winbind/) by asking him via E-Mail. As I'm sure this will help at least some people so here is his whole blog post:

---

## Scenario

File server running smbd, `security=ads` (i.e. acting as domain member), user connects to Samba share and gets group membership captured correctly
when connecting first time - and it never gets updated after that.

## Root cause

Samba updates group membership when it gets calculated by AD domain controller and it gets calculated only when user logs in to a server
running smbd and winbind. Which is triggered by `wbinfo -a` or kerberized SMB login only. As this is a serious limitation, meaning that no group
membership would be known at all on machines user never logs in on, fallback group membership code was developed that pulls group membership
of user from AD without user logging in but as machine account used by winbind does not have the rights to ask for user group membership it
is considered flaky with its results unreliable. Hence winbind never relies on it - it will call it when no group membership is known
at all but it will never be used to refresh cached group memberships. As result of that - in some scenarios winbind captures user group
memberships once and updates them never after that.

It is not possible to disable caching of group membership, i.e. there is no way to disable such behaviour by putting a line in `smb.conf`.
Note that this is not Samba issue but AD design issue, such behaviour is consistent with the way Windows behaves, which effectively is that
AD group membership is updated when a user authenticates during login.

## How to force group membership refresh for a user

Group membership is cached in a file named `netsamlogon_cache.tdb` which can be investigated
by tdbtool (all versions of Samba) or `net cache samlogon` (Samba 4.7 or newer). Deleting cached entries from that file triggers one time
update of group memberships by calling fallback update code and putting its result back in `netsamlogon_cache.tdb` - and after that they are cached forever again.

### tdbtool way:

```
$ wbinfo -n user.name
S-1-5-21-3023451936-689652692-1079546996-40725 SID_USER (1)
```

append `\0` to SID and put it in quotes:

```
$ tdbtool netsamlogon_cache.tdb delete "S-1-5-21-3023451936-689652692-1079546996-40725\0"
```

group membership will be updated first time the OS needs it, wait for a few minutes for tdb file to have it populated,

### net cache samlogon way:

```
$ net cache samlogon list|head
SID                                                Name                                     When cached
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
S-1-5-21-3023451936-689652692-1079546996-40725     DOM\user.name                            Tue Apr 27 07:59:19 AM 2018 BST
S-1-5-21-3023451936-689652692-1079546996-41432     DOM\user.name2                           Tue Apr 27 02:13:33 PM 2018 BST

$ net cache samlogon delete S-1-5-21-3023451936-689652692-1079546996-40725
```

Same as previously - group membership will be updated first time the OS needs it, wait for a few minutes for tdb file to have it populated.

---

Answer (score 1):

My only thought and it is a very vague one is that it might have something to do with communication with your Infrastructure Master (which is responsible for updating group memberships across domains).

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar experience with RHEL's stock samba/winbind packages.  It's been my experience that RHEL's winbind is a little sketchy.  What I observed was that once a user authenticated, their group membership would be accurately updated, but aside from that, no changes in group membership would ever show up.  This is not an optimal solution, particularly if you remove a user from a group that would grant them access to the machine, since it effectively gives them one last login that they shouldn't get.  This may or may not reflect your situation exactly though, because I also suffered from not seeing the group members of an AD group when running `getent group` (it would just look like a group with no members, even if `groups username` showed them as a member of the group), but it appears that is working for you.

What solved the problem for me was installing the "tested" distribution of RPMs from [enterprisesamba.org](http://www.enterprisesamba.org/index.php?id=123).  Group membership changes showed up immediately, regardless of winbind cache settings.  Required no configuration changes, BUT if you're mapping AD users and groups with a local idmap table installing the new RPMS will more than likely **completely remap your numeric group and user ids**, so be prepared for that (dump your `getent group` and g`etent passwd` output to a file before upgrading so you have a reference to fix file ownership with.

Comment: "What I observed was that once a user authenticated, their group membership would be accurately updated, but aside from that, no changes in group membership would ever show up." A note to others that may be helpful is that the key here is "*once a user authenticated*". I had similar problem where I would `su myaduser` (from root) and yet running `groups` showed that the AD changes had not applied. **Signing in as myaduser (ie. entering my password) seems to have properly updated the user's groups settings**.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar. To fix the problem I ran "authconfig --disablecache --update". Of course it made logons slow.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem here, and I found this link (https://marcinm.co.uk/group-membership-not-updating-in-winbind/) that explains in detail what happens.
Following the steps and deleting the records from the cache, my problem was solved.

Bye

Comment: Adding some more info on the steps you took to solve the problem will mean that if the link dies, other users can still benefit from your answer. Thanks!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/504333)

Comment: It's no longer an "if". The link is dead.